# C++: Pointer vs Pointer of Pointer to insert a node in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, pass-by-reference, dev-c++

I was creating a function to insert a element in a binary tree and, first, i did the following on Visual Studio 2012:

```
void Insert(Nodo *root, int x){
   if(root == NULL){
      Nodo *n = new Nodo();
      n->value = x
      root = n;
      return;
   }
   else{
      if(root->value > x)
         Insert(&(root)->left, x);
      else
         Insert(&(root)->right, x);
   }
}
```

But this same code doesn't work at Dev-C++, I need to use Pointer of Pointer to make it work, like this:

```
void Insert(Nodo **root, int x){
   if(*root == NULL){
      Nodo *n = new Nodo();
      n->value = x
      *root = n;
      return;
   }
   else{
      if((*root)->value > x)
         Insert(&(*root)->left, x);
      else
         Insert(&(*root)->right, x);
   }
}
```

Does anybody knows why it happens?

Comment: `root = n;` means nothing to the *caller* of your function., Your first example won't work at all if you start with a null root pointer on the caller-side, no matter what toolchain you're using (and to add salt to the wound, it will also leak memory). That you're also passing `int**` to a function asking for  `int*` when you pass `&(root)->left` (assuming `left` and `right` are pointers) is also wrong, and should have flaggeed phat warnings if you turned up your warning levels.

Comment: But why it worked in Visual Studio?  I could insert and search all the elements

Comment: If it did, it did so only because you primed `root` on the caller-side (the code for which is inconveniently missing in your post along with the node definition) with a non-null address to a valid `Node`. Even then, if `left` and `right` are `Nodo*`, then `&(root)->left` should be `Nodo**`, and that call shouldn't even *compile*. Perchance, did you have *both* of these implementations in the *same* source text when it magically compiled, and if so, have you considered the first may be calling the second via overload resolution on those recursions?

Comment: And I apologize for the `int*` and `int**` in my first comment, they should be `Nodo*` and `Nodo**` respectively. been a long day. Anyway, [see broken code here](http://ideone.com/aCnxPp).

Comment: @WhozCraig, now I saw the mistake, but I didnt get yet why the code does not work with just pointer, it has to be pointer of pointer to work

Comment: Because the thing you want to modify is the pointer *itself*; not just what it *points to*. Arrays (which express as a pointer-to-first-element when passed as a parameter) and C++ references notwithstanding, *all parameters in C/C++ are pass by value*. Which is to say, passing `Node*` passes the address *in* the pointer. That's not good enough. You need the address **of** the pointer so the pointer itself can be modified. Otherwise its not different than passing `int x`, calling `foo(n)`, and expecting `n` to be modified back on the caller side.

Comment: So in the first case (just one pointer) I was just telling the new pointer "root"  created by the function to point to the new nodo, and my left side of the previous nodo stills pointing to null.. right?

Comment: I tried to parse that sentence, and couldn't Your first code is just changing the value held by the local variable `root` (it is *just* a local variable; maybe that's the disconnect you're not seeing), which originally simply held *the value* of whatever you passed in. That change will have no affect on where the value *came from* by the caller. If you want to modify something by-address in C-fashion (which is what this is), then an address *of the thing you want to modify* is what you need to pass, declaring the parameter as a pointer-to-type and dereferencing that pointer to save to.

Comment: If you had a `int x` back in `main()` and you wanted to modify *it* via parameter, you declare a formal parameter `int *p` and pass `&x`, right? *Pointers are no different*. If you have a pointer you want to modify (not just what it points to, the pointer *itself*) `Type *p` back in `main()`, once again, declare a formal parameter as a pointer (in this case `Type **` since the thing we're modifying is `Type*`) and pass the pointer by address as well `foo(&p)`. It is no different. I honestly cannot explain it any better than that. if you still don't see it, any *decent* book on C will do.

Comment: hehe sorry about the sentence. But thank you, I get it now. I was miissing the part that the root was just a local variable on that function. I really have to have a pointer to pointer to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code should not compile.  In fact it doesn't compile under MSVC 2013.

**Why ?**

Your node structure should be something like this:

```
struct Nodo {
    int value; 
    Nodo*left, *right;  // pointer to the children nodes
};
```

This means that `(root)->left` is of type `Nodo*`.  Hence `&(root)->left` is of type `Nodo**` which is incompatible with a `Nodo*` argument.

Anyway,  in your insert function, you certainly want to change the tree.  But if you'd for example do:  `root = n;` you would just update the root argument (pointer).  This update is lost as soon as you leave the function.  Here, you certainly want to change either the content of the root node or more probably the pointer to a root node.

In the second version, you pass as argument the address of a pointer to a node, and then update this pointer when necessary (expected behaviour).

**Remark**

The first version could be "saved", if you would go for a pass by reference:

```
void Insert(Nodo * &root, int x){  // root then refers to the original pointer 
   if(root == NULL){   // if the original poitner is null... 
      Nodo *n = new Nodo();
      n->value = x
      root = n;        // the orginal pointer would be changed via the reference    
      return;
   }
   else{
      if(root->value > x)
         Insert(root->left, x);   // argument is the pointer that could be updated
      else
         Insert(root->right, x);
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get why if I say "hey pointer to the left Nodo, point to the same place that this new Nodo is pointo to", then after that the pointer to the left node will lost the reference, but if I use a Pointer to tell to the Left Pointer to do tha same thing, it works

Comment: Ops, I think I get it: my function will creat a pointer "root" to the pointer that was passed, so when I do "root = n", only the pointer that was created in this function will point to "n", not the left pointer of the previous Nodo. When I use pointer to pointer, I tell to the left pointer to point where I want... right?